# why there is oil in intake manifold of my demio zj engine?

Tags: vehicle-dynamics

Why is there oil in the intake manifold of my demio engine zj?
I have checked the valve seals are ok and piston rings also ok .

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please use the [edit] feature to add details about your vehicle. Year/Make/Model, mileage, etc. Also, how much oil is present? Without details, all we can go is make general broad guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Usually because a small amount is passed via PCV (positive crankcase ventilation) into the manifold. This is standard on most engines now to control emissions.